# Must I ground my dishwasher to a metal plate?

Tags: electrical, grounding, dishwasher

I bought a [Bosch 800 Series Dishwasher Model SHP68T55UC](http://www.lowes.com/pd_612562-39047-SHP68T55UC_0__?productId=50217963&Ntt=bosch%20800%20series%20dishwasher&pl=1&currentURL=%3FNtt%3Dbosch%2B800%2Bseries%2Bdishwasher&facetInfo=) to install into my year 2000 house. Whenever I read tutorials online for installing dishwashers, I see that the ground wire goes to a metal plate like so:

[image]

However, the instruction manual for my dishwasher never tells me to do that. It tells me to put all 3 wires into a box. The green ground wire never goes to the metal plate.

[image]
[image]

Here, I've followed the instruction manual. As you can see, I have a 3 pronged plug. The wall outlet under my kitchen sink also has 3 holes. I believe the 3 prongs correspond to the ground, neutral, and hot. Is this setup enough to ground my dishwasher? Why is virtually every other tutorial on the internet telling me to attach the ground wire to a metal plate? Is it because they assume you have a 2 pronged outlet with no grounding?

[image]

Comment: Virtually every other dishwasher does *not* come with  a break-out box. Refer to your manufacturer's specifications.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The green wire ends up connected to the chassis of the washer through the connector on the gray wire. If you'd open up the dishwasher you'd see one of the connectors going to a metal plate.

If you have a multimeter/continuity tester you can test this by checking the continuity between one of the connectors where the grey cable plugs in at the dishwasher and the chassis. The corresponding connector will be connected to the green wire.

This is done to reduce mistakes and questions from people who don't know here the green wire goes.

Besides that the black cable should be clamped down with a strain relief to remove stress on the copper wires. That would lead to bad connection arcing and general fire hazard.

Comment: So in layman's terms, does that mean it's already been grounded for me? And what is the name of the piece that holds the black cable securely in the plastic box's hole?

Comment: @JoJo -- that clamp is a "strain relief" :)